# Add mono.android reference Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im working on a Xamarin.Forms project and I need to work with mono.android things. The problem is that in a project before, I do have the reference, but in the new one, I Cannot add it. Is there a way to do it ? or while creating the project ? or something ?

[This is the project where I have Mono.Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y7nF.png)

[I dont have it in this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaKkE.png)

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "work with mono.android things"?

Comment: In your shared code you cannot reference mono android. You can run some platform specific code using Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android but generally for "working with mono.android things" you need to create custom renderer.

Comment: @Carlos, Why you want to add mono.android reference in Forms? If you want to call  platform specific code in PCL, you can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Answer (score 3):

In solution explorer, right click on References. 
Click on Add Reference. 
Click on Browse on the left panel. 
Verify the mono.android has a check mark on it. 
Click on Browse in the bottom.

Enter this path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1

Select Mono.Android.dll. 
This should add the reference to mono.android!

Comment: For Mac? Edit reference shows nothing, What to do?

Comment: I posted a full response for the case of Mac

Answer (score 0):

I've read that you have to remove your references in a PCL project or use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) but I didn't understand very well how to do it, so I came with a (not very orthodox) solution:

I copied from VS Windows in a Windows machine the Mono.Android.dll, Java.Interop.dll and the Xamarin.iOS.dll to the root folder on my project on VS Mac, then make the following references on the project's file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
    <HintPath>Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Java.Interop">
    <HintPath>Java.Interop.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">
    <HintPath>Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then I added the assembly reference on Android's folder

[image]

And in the .NET Assembly tab, I browsed for the dll's (Mono.Android + Java.Interop for Android and Xamarin.iOS + Java.Interop for iOS)

[image]

And my project compiled on VS Mac.